# HTML Body align as center

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried all the possibilities but surely somewhere I am mistaking. I am creating a bootstrap website (http://design.logohour.com) site seems ok as well as aligned well in center, but when I am trying to change the screen size lesser than 850px or more less, all the content goes to the left.

I know there is something wrong with CSS but unable to find out since I want all my content in the center without overflow-x ... need an expert opinion.

Comment: Hmmm... looks centered for me all the way down to 300px. Nothing went left aligned for me when I checked. What device/browser are you using?

Comment: Google chrome I have cleared cache but still its bad at my end

Comment: Ok this is funny .. I have spent almost an hour and finally when I checked on mozilla its showing fine .... so why Chrome showing such alignement

Comment: Cache on the server? All i know is I am using Chrome and it is fine.

Comment: Seems to be working fine on Chrome for me as well.  I'm voting to close as a problem that can no longer be reproduced,

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine on my end!

Your cache is probably outdated. Try these things to see if it solves:

1) Assuming you're using Google Chrome, open an incognito window and view the site.

Why? Incognito mode will allow you to view your site without using cache

2) Refresh your cache using the web inspector.

If you open up the web inspector (Right click and click "Inspect") you unlock a magical way to clear your cache. With the web inspector open, right click the reload button and empty the cache.
[image: Empty cache and hard reload]

Good luck solving the issue!